# run rand() func on each iteration of str_repeat

Tags: php, random

I'm trying to formulate some dummy data so that I can developed the front end of a html data table, to do this im writing the data out once and using `str_repeat` to out put it multiple times.

One of the features I'm incorporating in the front end is the ability to sort columns but to do that I need different data in each row. I planned to use `rand()` to assist with this part, but when I use it with the code block below, it generates a random number and the `str_repeat` outputs that 3 times..

Is there a simple way to get it to run the `rand()` func on each iteration of the `str_repeat()` func ?

```
$html = "
          <tr>
            <!-- Unit Price -->
              <td class='table-input input-number'>
                <input class='input-center' value='" . rand(10,200) . "'>
              </td>

            <!-- QTY -->
              <td class='table-input input-number'>
                <input class='input-center' value='" . rand(1,5) . "'>
              </td>
          </tr>";

        echo str_repeat($html,3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach i ended up using is this below based on @Christoph's answer, with this approach it lets you input the html and the `rand()` values in a more straight forward fashion.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
   echo "<tr>
        <!-- Unit Price -->
          <td class='table-input input-number'>
            <input class='input-center'" . rand(1,5) . "'>
          </td>

        <!-- QTY -->
          <td class='table-input input-number'>
            <input class='input-center'" . rand(1,5) . "'>
          </td>
      </tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it with `str_repeat`, because you have a *fixed* string, which is repeated. Use e.g.

```
$tmpl = "
  <tr>
    <!-- Unit Price -->
      <td class='table-input input-number'>
        <input class='input-center' value='%d'>
      </td>

    <!-- QTY -->
      <td class='table-input input-number'>
        <input class='input-center' value='%d'>
      </td>
  </tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    printf($tmpl, rand(10, 200), rand(1, 5));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i end up using a slightly different approach based on your answer, mainly due to the fact it makes writing the html easier on my end. See my answer below